# Remember selected checkboxes across paginated pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am displaying data in a table and doing some paging and sorting. I have a checkbox for everyrow. 
 When I move from one page to another, I will like to keep the checkboxes checked if they were checked.
 I dont want the checked boxes to uncheck as I navigate from page to page. How do i achieve that?

Here is my jquery.

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {

                    $(".header").click(function (evt) {
                        var sortfield = $(evt.target).data("sortfield");
                        if ($("#SortField").val() == sortfield)
                        {
                            if($("#SortDirection").val()=="ascending")
                            {
                                $("#SortDirection").val("descending");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $("#SortField").val(sortfield);
                            $("#SortDirection").val("ascending");
                        }
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $("form").submit();
                    });

                    $(".pager").click(function (evt) {
                        var pageindex = $(evt.target).data("pageindex");
                        $("#CurrentPageIndex").val(pageindex);
                        evt.preventDefault();
                        $("form").submit();
                    });

                });
            </script>


Here is my html page

            <body>
            <h1>List of Customers</h1>
            @{
                PageSortOnlineEx.Models.SortingPagingInfo info = ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo;
            }

            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {

                @Html.Hidden("SortField", info.SortField)
                @Html.Hidden("SortDirection", info.SortDirection)
                @Html.Hidden("PageCount", info.PageCount)
                @Html.Hidden("PageSize", info.PageSize)
                @Html.Hidden("CurrentPageIndex", info.CurrentPageIndex)


                <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr>
                        <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="">Select</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="CustomerID" class="header">CustomerID</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="CompanyName" class="header">CompanyName</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="ContactName" class="header">ContactName</a></th>
                        <th><a href="#" data-sortfield="Country" class="header">Country</a></th>

                    </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@Html.CheckBox("select", false)</td>
                            <td>@item.CustomerID</td>
                            <td>@item.CompanyName</td>
                            <td>@item.ContactName</td>
                            <td>@item.Country</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4">
                            @for (var i = 0; i < info.PageCount; i++)
                            {
                                if (i == info.CurrentPageIndex)
                                {
                                    <span>@(i + 1)</span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <a href="#" data-pageindex="@i" class="pager">@(i + 1)</a>
                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
        </body>
```

Here is my controller code

```
        public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
                    {
                        SortingPagingInfo info = new SortingPagingInfo();
                        info.SortField = "CustomerID";
                        info.SortDirection = "ascending";
                        info.PageSize = 10;
                        info.PageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling((double)(db.Customers.Count() / info.PageSize)));
                        info.CurrentPageIndex = 0;

                        var query = db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerID).Take(info.PageSize);

                        ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo = info;
                        List<Customer> model = query.ToList();

                        return View(model);
                    }
                }


                [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult Index(SortingPagingInfo info)
                {
                    using (NorthwindEntities db = new NorthwindEntities())
                    {
                        IQueryable<Customer> query = null;

                        switch (info.SortField)
                        {
                            case "CustomerID":
                                query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ? db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerID) : db.Customers.OrderByDescending(c => c.CustomerID));
                                break;
                            case "CompanyName":
                                query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ? db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.CompanyName) : db.Customers.OrderByDescending(c => c.CompanyName));
                                break;
                            case "ContactName":
                                query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ? db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.ContactName) : db.Customers.OrderByDescending(c => c.ContactName));
                                break;
                            case "Country":
                                query = (info.SortDirection == "ascending" ? db.Customers.OrderBy(c => c.Country) : db.Customers.OrderByDescending(c => c.Country));
                                break;
                        }
                        query = query.Skip(info.CurrentPageIndex * info.PageSize).Take(info.PageSize);

                        ViewBag.SortingPagingInfo = info;
                        List<Customer> model = query.ToList();

                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: If you want to persist the data, then you need to send the values of the checkboxes to the controller and save them somewhere so that you can retrieve them.

Comment: Do you have some code samples you can share please? Thank you.

Comment: Using the way you suggested, How do I retrieve the saved items looking at my code above?